# `glCopyTexImage2D` using `GL_RGB8_OES` extension on OpenGL ES 2.0 iPhone 6.1

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

When I call

```
glCopyTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB8_OES, 0, 0, w, h, 0 );
```

I get `GLERROR 1281 GL_INVALID_VALUE`.  If I use

```
glCopyTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 0, 0, w, h, 0 );
```

It works fine.

It seems `GL_RGB8_OES` is unsupported for `glCopyTexImage2D`!  Such a glaring omission, I find that hard to believe.  How can I rescue the alpha channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using GL_RGBA ?

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCopyTexImage2D.xml

Comment: Ah, very clever sir.  It works and keeps the alpha channel.  I wonder why they bothered to define `GL_RGB8_OES` then.

Comment: Well you have to use `GL_RGBA8_OES` when calling `glRenderBufferStorage`.  If you pass `GL_RGBA` there, you get 1280 Invalid Enum.